# 'functionally' remove value/key from an object depending on another object keys/values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Here are 2 objects:

```
object1: {
    email: somevalue
    url: somevalue
    description: somevalue
}

object2: {
    email: someothervalue
    url: someothervalue
}
```

Goal, remove from object1, any key/value pair, for each key that doesn't exist on object2. Objects can't be merged because values are very different for each object.

This can be done with traditional imperative structure, but i'm looking for a more 'functional' way to do it, with help of lodash library.
Do you know a way to do so, so the result will be:

```
object1: {
    email: somevalue
    url: somevalue
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you can do the following:

```
_.pick(object1, Object.keys(object2))
```

This produces a *new object*.

Comment: This is nice if having a new object is OK.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need lodash.

```
Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!(key in object2))
    delete object1[key];
});
```